# Internal 500 error on Google Compute Engine, installing littlest jupyter

Tags: google-compute-engine, internal-server-error, jupyterhub

"Internal 500 server error" after VM runs for a day or two.

This is the second time it has happened, I start the instance, install littlest Jupyterhub
(see details below). I can login to the external ip, for a day, but then it stops
with internal 500 error. I cannot ssh or get into the instance, only alternate is to
create a new instance and re-do. What is the problem?

I have installed littlest jupyterhub using on this instance, using
#!/bin/bash
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jupyterhub/the-littlest-jupyterhub/master/bootstrap/bootstrap.py | sudo python3 - --admin master

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you enable access on your instance to the serial console [1].
You will also need to setup a password for your user following this documentation [2].

With these two steps done, you should be able to reconnect to your instance once you are locked out like you mentioned by following this [3].

You should then be able to investigate what is going on in the instance.

Then try to verify if your application is still running, if the SSH server is still running etc.

Frederic

[1] https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console#enable_instance_access
[2] https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console#setting_up_a_local_password
[3] https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console#connectserialconsole